# Prove that ≿ is transitive iff ≻ and ∼ are transitive (revamp)

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, relations, game-theory

[image: My work so far]

Above is my work so far. I know this question was asked before but it did not have a definite answer in it, which is why I'm asking it once more.

Comment: What is it that you're looking for from us specifically? Do you need help finishing the proof? Do you need any clarification on any part of the proof so far (I know you wrote it, but you did tag [tag:proof-explanation])? Did you want us to check the proof so far and provide feedback?

Comment: I would like it if someone could provide the rest of the proof and make it complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\succ$ and $\sim$ are transitive and consider $x, y, z$ such that $x \succsim y$ and $y \succsim z$. Since $\succsim$ is a total relation, we must have $x \succsim  z$ (in which case we're done), or $z \succsim x$. We will suppose the former is false, and hence the latter is true, in order to obtain a contradiction.

Therefore, $z \succ x$. If $\lnot(y \succsim x)$, then $x \succ y$, so by transitivity of $\succ$, we get $z \succ y$. This would contradict $y \succsim z$, hence $y \succsim x$, and thus $x \sim y$.

Similarly, if $\lnot(z \succsim y)$, then $y \succ z$. By the transitivity of $\succ$, we get $y \succ x$, contradicting $x \succsim y$. We similarly get $y \sim z$.

By transitivity of $\sim$, we see that $x \sim z \implies x \succsim z$ after all, which contradicts our assumption.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply. I was able to understand until the point where you said "Therefore z≻x." Because you assumed by contradiction that z≿x , then this means either (z≻x) or (z∼x) is true. So I guess we would have to examine each case (z≻x), (z∼x) with this exclusion in mind.
Let's say that you were in fact examining the case where z≻x is true and z∼x is false. Then "Therefore z≻x." makes sense. But after that how did you come up with ¬(y≿x) being true?

Comment: @deniz I specifically assumed $\lnot(x \succsim z)$ because, as I said, if it were true, then we'd be done. This implies $z \succsim x$, by the totality of the relation. Thus, in total, we have $(z \succsim x) \land \lnot(x \succsim z)$, the very definition of $z \succ x$. I then prove that $\lnot(y \succsim x)$ through contradiction, and transitivity of $\succ$, as the rest of the paragraph proves.